# Getting Width and Height of Modal on iPad Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, modal-dialog, popover

I'm trying to get the width of the modal on an iPad so I can use it to calculate position of the component inside. I was expecting this to give the width, but it's actually returning the with of the device instead.

```
self.view.frame.size.width
```

What's the right way to do this?

This is how I invoke the view controller to bring up the modal.

```
let scannerViewController = ScannerViewController(barcodeCallback: queueBarcode, cameraScanDismissedCallback: cameraScanDismissedCallback)
present(scannerViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: You should use auto layout / constraints -- that way you don't have to do any frame calculations.

Comment: @DonMag The problem I have is that I need to correctly position AVCaptureMetadataOutput.rectOfInterest and it's a CGRect. Is that still possible with constraint?

Comment: As a general rule, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is when you know what the frames are. Give us a little more to go on... Edit your post with a detailed description of what you're trying to do, show the code you're using, and describe what's not working.